# Merging Data on a Google sheet depending on the column header description

Tags: google-sheets

I'm relatively new to Google Sheets and I'm faced with a small challenge.

I've created a long Google form which has caused multiple of the same heading on Google sheets.

How do I go about joining multiple rows so I can filter the data?

I've attached a screenshot of my spreadsheeet with blue arrows showing the columns I need to merge.

Every item needs to be on its own line [image: Example]

Comment: Please share your a copy of your spreadsheet. Remove any private or confidential data. Make sure that include an example of a successful outcome.